# What is going on in 〜だしよう

Tags: grammar, meaning

The line comes from a short exchange in a game. The character is surprised seeing the protagonist walk into a practice room that he's been using, and later says the following:

> 今日はこれからみっちり、俺様が予約を入れているはずだしよう

which i understand as an assertion that the room is supposed to be booked for him (for the rest of the day, perhaps? The みっちり is tripping me up a bit), but what is the meaning of "しよう" here and how does it connect to the rest of the sentence grammatically? Is it a する conjugation or a totally different word?

Comment: @Angelos It definitely says だしよう in the text, but if that's the case perhaps it's a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the character speaks roughly, it is likely to be だ+し+よう, where

- だ is the auxiliary verb for assertion
- [し](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%97/#jn-92431) is a particle indicating reason (def #3)
- よう is a prolonged version of [よ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%88/#jn-226011), ending particle for emphasis.

Your interpretation should be correct.